# Node JS - Nginx - proxy_pass to a subdirectory - Koa

Tags: node.js, nginx, koa, proxypass

I'm running a Koa app on port 5000, and i'd like Ngnix to serve the app in a sub-directory - e.g: `http://example.com/myNodeApp`

Here's what I've currently got in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
        location ^~ /myNodeApp/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000/;
        }
```

This *kind of* works... apart from the fact that any redirect e.g `this.redirect('/')` in my Koa app goes to the the nginx web root `/`

Also, it doesn't render anything from my Koa apps' `public` directory e.g. stylesheets, javascript and images.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using regexp match of location? Switch to simple string match `location /myNodeApp/ {`

Comment: Thanks @Terra. I read a similar SO question where they did this and thought I would try it too. Changing to `location /myNodeApp/ { ... }` (without the regular expression as you suggested), gives the same result.

Comment: Can you check and show full `Location` header? With domain part. Because `Location` header rewriting work only if your node application redirect to http://localhost:5000/. But if node application redirects to http://localhost/ - custom rewrite required. So, need to know how location header looks like.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking Terra (sorry). I have a stock nginx config, and have bolted the code above inside the `server { ... }` block. This is all a bit new to me!

Comment: `curl -I http://localhost:5000
    

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 2730
    Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 20:49:53 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Can you `curl` node's URL which execute `this.redirect('/')`

Comment: Oh, let me explain that you need to find. Read this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect, especially default behavior. Node application doing redirect with HTTP header `Location: http://xxxxx/xxx`. Depend on domain part - nginx can rewrite it or not. If this domain part `localhost:5000` - nginx can rewrite this redirect as default behavior. If node application using another domain part (`http://localhost/xxxx` for example) - you need to add custom `proxy_redirect` directive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have recently come across the same problem and here's what I did to fix it.

**In Server Config:**

I had to add

```
rewrite ^/myNodeApp/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

to the NGINX config, in the

```
location /myNodeApp/ {...}
```

block, under what you already have in your example.

**In client side:**

I added

```
<base href='/myNodeApp/'>
```

to the <head> of my html files (or pug layout file in my case). This prefixes any links with your subdirectory.

Note that you will need to remove any leading /'s from your existing links. Eg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout.css">
```

That one caught me out for a while.

**Bonus:**

If you're using Socket.IO, like I am, you'll need to make a few more changes to stop some errors appearing in your console. You need to pass it a path option and specify your subdirectory.

In your html files

```
var socket = io.connect("/", {path: "/myNodeApp/socket.io"})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - this was exactly what I was looking for. +1